# How to center text vertically in a heading?

Tags: html, css

I have an `<h1>` element that has width and height set. I want to vertically center the text in it, but I can't seem to do it. The text can be either single or multi-lined. Please see my code below:

```css
h1 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #888;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<h1>Test</h1>
```

Comment: try `line-height: 150px;` instead of `height`

Comment: @NicolasBouvrette Yes that was already suggested but the text can wrap and using the `line-height` solution breaks if that happens.

Comment: Then simply use `padding: 70px 0;`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The following solutions work for both single or multi-lined text.

#### 1. Flexbox:

```css
h1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>A quick brown fox</h1>
```

#### 2. CSS table-cell:

```css
h1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>A quick brown fox</h1>
```

#### 3. Line height (+`<span>`):

```css
h1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;      
}
```

```html
<h1><span>A quick brown fox</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 5):

If there is only one line of text, just set the `line-height` to 150px:

```css
h1 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  background-color: #888888;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<h1>Test</h1>
```

However, this will only work if the text doesn't wrap. If it does, you can use flexbox to center it:

```css
h1 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  background-color: #888888;
  color: white;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<h1>Super Monkey!</h1>
```